# Trying to install VirtualBox onto Ubuntu but having problems with the need restart is being skipped since spiky has failed

Tags: virtualbox

```
duo@duo-server-1:~/Downloads$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... Done 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
virtualbox-7.0
• upgraded, • newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 220 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 199368 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.8-156879-Ubuntu-jammy)
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2)
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-lubuntu3)
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2)
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+mulubuntul)
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-lubuntu3) 
needrestart is being skipped since pkg has failed 
duo@duo-server-1:~/Downloads$
```

Comment: Virtualbox `7.0.8-156879-Ubuntu-jammy` is not an Ubuntu package, which suggests that you have installed non-Ubuntu packages from non-Ubuntu sources. Uninstall all packages that came from those non-Ubuntu sources. Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible, and clean up all the detritus if your past mistakes. Then install Virtualbox the easy way -- from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: OR ... Reinstall Ubuntu and start over.

Comment: "spiky has failed" means what?